# Ajuda com ajax para mandar novo valor de variavel na emsma pagina sem refresh via radio button

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

pessoal tou tentando fazer uma tabela com radio que quando clica, muda a ordem que é exibidido o conteudo da tabela, vi que o jeito para fazer isso é com ajax, mas eu não tenho muito tempo restando, e pelo que vi de ajax não consegui entender para usar nisso. se alguem puder me ajduar a mostrar como ficaria uma função ajax que manda o valor de dentro de um radio para o php na mesma pagina sem dar refresh, agradeço muito, só falta isso para o fim do meu tcc(de ensino médio), e não entendo nada de ajax. segue abaixo a função do ajax e minha falha tentativa de fazer os radios mudarem o valor de $modo.

```
echo "<form name='busca' method='GET' >";
      echo "<table><tr><td>";
      echo "<input type='radio' checked name='modo' value='0' onSelect=" $modo = 0; ">Mais curtidos</td><td>";
      echo "<input type='radio' name='modo' value='1' onSelect=" $modo = 1; ">Menos curtidos</td></tr><td>";
      echo "<input type='radio' name='modo' value='2' onSelect=" $modo = 2; ">Mais novos</td><td>";
      echo "<input type='radio' name='modo' value='3' onSelect=" $modo = 3; ">Mais antigos</td></tr>";
      echo "</table>";

       switch($modo){
            case "0":
                    $varsql = "SELECT * FROM $tab WHERE TIPO='$tipo' ORDER BY likes DESC";
                    break;

            case "1": 
                    $varsql = "SELECT * FROM $tab WHERE TIPO='$tipo' ORDER BY likes ASC";
                    break;

           case "2": 
                    $varsql = "SELECT * FROM $tab WHERE TIPO='$tipo' ORDER BY id DESC";
                    break;


          case "3": 
                    $varsql = "SELECT * FROM $tab WHERE TIPO='$tipo' ORDER BY id ASC";
                    break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode elaborar dessa forma, com o jquery e busca os dados via ajax, e lista.

**Página para verificação:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='radio' name='modo' class='modo' value='0'>Mais curtidos</td>
        <td><input type='radio' name='modo' class='modo' value='1'>Menos curtidos</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type='radio' name='modo' class='modo' value='2'>Mais novos</td>
        <td><input type='radio' name='modo' class='modo' value='3'>Mais antigos</td>    
    </tr>
<table>

<div id="listagem"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    $(".modo").click(function(){
        var modo = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'listagem.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {modo:modo},
            success: function(data) {
                $("#listagem").html(data); // data é o retorno da sua pagina
            }
        });             
    });
</script>
```

**Listagem.php**

```
<?php
    $modo = $_POST['modo']; // Este é o modo que veio do radio selecionado

    switch($modo){
        case "0":
        $varsql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tab." WHERE TIPO = '".$tipo."' ORDER BY likes DESC";
        break;

        case "1": 
        $varsql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tab." WHERE TIPO = '".$tipo."' ORDER BY likes ASC";
        break;

        case "2": 
        $varsql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tab." WHERE TIPO = '".$tipo."' ORDER BY id DESC";
        break;

        case "3": 
        $varsql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tab." WHERE TIPO = '".$tipo."' ORDER BY id ASC";
        break;
    }

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($conn, $varsql)){
        echo $row["campo"];
    }       
?>
```

Desta forma você consegue recuperar todos os dados, conforme o seu select.

Comment: esse #listagem serviria para que? e no meu caso o php está na mesma pagina que a tabela. tanto que está dando erro de undefined index no modo.

Comment: Não pode ser na mesma página, tem que ser em outra página separada, para o ajax chamar a pagina da forma correta e exibir..

Comment: mas se eu colocasse toda a parte do php em outra pagina como eu faria para ele receber a variável que é mandada para a pagina html? com o include funcionaria normal?